# How to wait for button disable status in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

The code below waits for element to be present:

```
    var elm = element(by.css('button.submit'));

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);
    elm.click();
```

Code to check if button is enabled and this can be used for clicking:

```
    expect(elm.isEnabled().toBe(false));
```

In my conditions, form validation is performing too fast. So that the button is enabled and disabled bit slow. Not able to capture the status of element. Both above conditions are not working to check if the button got disabled or not.

How to check for button disabled status other than using `browser.sleep(1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I create a new recursive function to identify if it is enabled/present.

```
function checkIfDisabled(maxSec, elm, blnDisabled) {
    if (maxSec > 0) {
        browser.sleep(1000).then(function() {
            elm.isDisabled().then(function(bln) {
                if (bln != blnDisabled) {
                    checkIfDisabled(maxSec - 1, elm, blnPresent)
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If you pass checkIfDisabled(10, elm, false)
It will check if the object is disabled for 10 times with 1 sec interval.
Hope it helps. :)